# Synchronize rest application and saving to file

Tags: java, rest, wildfly

I've got kinda weird situation, I have methods:

```
public void generateRecords(Request request) {
    String pathToFile = request.getPathFile();
    String recordOne = generateRecordOne(request);
    String recordTwo = generateRecordTwo(request);

    fileService.writeToFile(pathToFile, recordOne);
    fileService.writeToFile(pathToFile, recordTwo);
}

public void writeToFile(String path, String content) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path, true);
            writer.append(content);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStack();
        }
}
```

generateRecords() is executing is rest endpoint. I am getting something like this:

```
id:1:record1 

id:2:record1 

id:1:record2

id:2:record2
```

While I would like to get something like this:

```
id:1:record1 

id:1:record2 

id:2:record1

id:2:record2
```

It is occuring sometimes, but still it is destroying my file. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `synchronized` on writeToFile method.

Also, consider using the try-with-resources statement. In the code you have right now, an exception in your writer would lead to not closing the FileWriter.

```
public synchronized void writeToFile(String path, String content) {
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path, true)) {            
        writer.append(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```